# Getting an error in JMeter TCP Sampler, but I am receiving data well

Tags: tcp, jmeter

I am trying TCP connection with C# server through JMeter
Receive Base64 encoded data from C# server and try to decode it in JMeter

Current TCP Sampler settings are as follows

```
TCPClient classname: TCPClientImpl
Timeouts Response: 1000
Re-use connection: true
Close connection: true
Set NoDelay: false
SO_LINGER: [EMPTY]
End of line(EOL) byte value: 03
```

When connecting to a server by adding a TCP Sampler, the following error message is received from the server.

```
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 116
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Sampler Result

```
Thread Name:LoginTest 1-1
Sample Start:2020-11-12 14:24:54 KST
Load time:1079
Connect Time:0
Latency:71
Size in bytes:116
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:116
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 116


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: x-windows-949
```

However, unlike the error message, packet data is being delivered from the actual server.

When I added the JSR223 Listner and checked the received data, I confirmed that the desired data is being received properly.

Data is being received normally. Why is there an error? Is it a C# server problem?

I have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself

The cause was an incorrect End of line bytes value.

Because it receives Base64 encoded data from the C# server,
Base64 padding'=' comes in at the end of the stream.
I entered 61, the ASCII value of'=' as the End of line byte value, and the result was success.

But i am not sure if this is the correct solution
Please let me know if there is a more suitable solution